# Is $C^{\gamma}(\Sigma)$ dense in $C(\Sigma)$?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Consider $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology and $\Sigma=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the product topology. We know that this 
product topology is generated by the metric
$$
d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{|x_i-y_i|}{2^i}.
$$

Denote by $C(\Sigma)$ the space of all continuous functions 
$f:\Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$ and $C^{\gamma}(\Sigma)$ the subset 
of $C(\Sigma)$ of all $f$ such that 
$$
Hol(f)=\sup_{x\neq y}\dfrac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d(x,y)^{\gamma}}<\infty
$$

We consider on $C(\Sigma)$ the sup norm, i.e, $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in \Sigma}|f(x)|$
and on $C^{\gamma}(\Sigma)$ the "Hölder norm" defined by $\|f\|_{\gamma}=\|f\|+Hol(f)$.

**Fact:** $C^{\gamma}(\Sigma)$, $0\leq\gamma  <1$ is dense in $C(\Sigma)$ in the uniform norm.

**New setting:** Let $(M,d)$ be a compact metric space, and $\Sigma=M^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the product topology. $\Sigma$ is compact by Tychonov's  Theorem. The product topology is generated by the metric
$$
d_{\Sigma}(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{d(x_i,y_i)}{2^i}
$$
In an analogously way we  the spaces $C(\Sigma)$ and $C^{\gamma}(\Sigma)$
and the norms $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\gamma}$ over $C(\Sigma)$ and $C^{\gamma}(\Sigma)$ respectively, they are both well defined because $\Sigma$ is compact.

**My Question:** Is, for $0<\gamma<1$, $C^{\gamma}(\Sigma)$ dense in $C(\Sigma)$ in the uniform norm?

Comment: Use Stone-Weierstrass on functions which depend only on finitely many co-ordinates?

Comment: In fact, the Lipschitz functions are already dense. This follows from from Stone-Weierstrass.

Comment: Also, taking the product is pointless in your general setting since: (1) you can right away take $M=\Sigma$; (2) the functions on $\Sigma$ could depend on just the first coordinate.